# Documentation for clang's libraries

Tags: c++, c, clang

I'm using clang's libraries to write a program that will take the parsed 
code and put it into a structure.
is there any up to date information about clang's libraries?
reference and tutorial would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [doc](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/) and a [tut](http://amnoid.de/tmp/clangtut/tut.html) and a [tut more](http://clangtutorial.codeplex.com/).

Edit: A [newer tutorial](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial). Should only be 5 days old.

You might want to have a look at the [clang Internals Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/InternalsManual.html) and the [cfe-dev](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/) mailing list.

Comment: OK thanks the docs are good. but the tutorial looks kind of old and the tutorial more I can't get them to compile something maybe wrong with it. I'm on ubuntu 11.10 i have llvm and clang installed in /opt/LLVM from source.

Comment: OK the docs clang manual is excellent. I can also get the clang tutorial to compile but it won't link for some reason any idea? i fallows this to install  LLVM and clang http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html

Comment: here is my log file for the build http://ice-os.com/error.log should i maybe build LLVM/Clang from a certain version?

Comment: And what are you linking it against?

Comment: I run make in the tutorials it links with whats in there g++ -o tutorial1 tutorial1.o -lclangParse -lclangSerialization -lclangDriver -lclangSema -lclangAnalysis -lclangAST -lclangFrontend -lclangLex -lclangBasic -lLLVMSupport  -L/opt/LLVM/lib  -lpthread -ldl -lm  -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMCore -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMMC -lLLVMSupport

Comment: Make sure the libraries can be found by the linker, so try to add `-L/path/to/libs` to infer this.

Comment: OK thank you it finally worked my LLVM/Clang has been rebuilt now no problems.